# Construct SimpleXMLelement with xml header only in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have following code

```
$xml_start = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml></xml>');
```

and I need to get rid of the  tags. Any tag name works, but when I remove the tags I get an exception 'String could not be parsed as XML'. I can't figure out how to initialize the SimpleXMLelement with the header string `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` only. Also, is it possible to somehow initialize the SimpleXMLelement object without any input data and then append to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php)

The SimpleXMLElement() constructor requires a well-formed xml document or a URL that points to an XML document. By only including a header, you are not defining the content of the document, and therefore it is by definition, not [well defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).